# Sharepoint 2013 callout is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

i have been developing extension for sharepoint. I was trying to implement custom callout for document library (using fancytree for library content presentation).
For reference I have used https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/highlight-content-and-enhance-the-functionality-of-sharepoint-hosted-sharepoint.

I have defined callout functionality in a separate function execCallout(data). 
(for simplicity functionality with data is omitted).

I have two scenarious: execCallout is initiated/called by the user (no preloaded data) and execCallout is loaded with starting data. In both cases i use the same execCallout.

```
function execCallout (data) {
console.log("demo");
//get our launchpoint - where callout will appear
var targetElement = document.querySelectorAll(".fancytree-active.fancytree-focused .fancytree-title")[0];


//Configure new Callout
var calloutOptions = new CalloutOptions();
calloutOptions.ID = 'MyCustomCallOut';
calloutOptions.launchPoint = targetElement;
calloutOptions.beakOrientation = 'leftRight';
calloutOptions.content = ' My Content';
calloutOptions.title = 'My Title';

// check for current callout
var myCallOut = CalloutManager.createNewIfNecessary(calloutOptions);

//Create custom action for callout
var myAction = new CalloutActionOptions();
myAction.text = 'My Special Action';
myAction.onClickCallback = function(event, action)
{
    alert("I can do whatever you want");
};

var newAction = new CalloutAction(myAction);

//Add the action to the callout
myCallOut.addAction(newAction);
myCallOut.set({ openOptions: { event: "hover" } }); //or click
myCallOut.open();
```

}

The first scenario works fine, i.e., on user click callout is initiated/execCallout is called.

However, when with preloaded data i get "Uncaught ReferenceError: myCallOut is not defined" (from debugger console i see that function was called, however calloutManager has no callout associated with my launchPoint). It looks as if the calloutManager was not initiated. 
At any time initiated execCallout from debugger console fixes the problem.

Ideas what and where is missing are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

My quess about the issue: the problem was caused by fancytree rendering. The callout was initiated while the "tree" was not fully rendered. By default during rendering values were "lost", therefore default tree rendering was causing problem.

Solution: manually initiated tree rendering prior to callout operations, so that no values/variables were gone.